# Chrome for mac reports my ASP.NET session cookie as not being Secure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, ssl

I've got SSL enabled, requireSSL enabled, etc. etc. and on my windows PC, Chrome and Firefox mark the cookie as being 'Httponly' and 'Secure'.

However, on Chrome for Mac, it does not mark it as Secure.

I am not sure if this is a bug on Chrome, or if the cookie is not being transmitted securely.

Is this a known issue, or is there an easy way to test this? I had a worry that it was 'falling back' to non SSL which is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've ever experienced something similar was when there was already an existing cookie before the secure and HttpOnly flags were set. Try clearing your cookies in Chrome or simply remove the specific cookie(s) for your site by going to the "Resources" tab in Chrome's developer panel (while on your site).